# Gas pilot will not light

Tags: furnace, pilot-light

I have a very old forced air heater in my house. When I try to light the pilot it will not light. It has gas coming out of it because the pressure of the gas even tries to blow the match out when I try to light it. Any ideas?

Comment: maybe air in the line. no gas until air is forced out.

Comment: What make and model? Can you get a pressure gauge on the line?